# php curl adding slashes to xml attributes

Tags: php, post, curl, quotes

trying to post some xml with curl but it keeps adding slashes to "s.

I'm sending it to a server i don't hav access so cant encode/decode...

```
$xmlToPost = '<PurchaseItems DISCOUNT="0" NETLINEVAL="0" PACK_CODE="0" VAT="0" PurchaseOrderNumber="'.$_POST['txn_id'].'">'; // just a snippet!

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://193.128.105.227/sukishufu/externalcom/AddXMLOrder.cfm?ClientSys=sukishufu");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'ClientUrl=SukuOffice01&OrderXML='.stripslashes($xmlToPost));

$btbResponse = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

strip slashes doesn't work? Any help welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have [magic_quotes](http://www.php.net/magic_quotes) turned on on your server. This will auto-add slashes to any POST / GET variable. I would turn that off and see if it fixes it (and remove the `stripslashes` section when done).

If you do not have access to modify the php.ini or not able to set that in the .htaccess file, you would need to `stripslashes` on the POST variable, not the `$xmlToPost`

Comment: cheers - did that with a htaccess file so the rest of the server stays as is. XML file still not getting through but i think its another problem...